# Inherited Window can not have a name?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance

I'm having trouble with naming my Window which is inherited from its Base Window,
when I try to give a name to my Window I get following error.

> The type BaseWindow cannot have a Name attribute. Values types and types without a default constructor can be used as items within ResourceDictionary.

**XAML :**

```
<log:BaseWindow 
   x:Class="EtraabMessenger.MainWindow"
   x:Name="main"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
   xmlns:log="clr-namespace:EtraabMessenger.MVVM.View.Controls" 
   xmlns:VMCore="clr-namespace:EtraabMessenger.MVVM.VMCore" 
   VMCore:WindowClosingBehavior.Closing="{Binding DoCloseMainWindowCommand}"
   Height="464" Width="279">

</log:BaseWindow>
```

**EDIT** : Here is my BaseWindow class

```
public abstract class BaseWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected BaseWindow()
    {
        // Note (Important) : This message should register on all windows
        // TODO : I'm planning to move this registeration to BaseWindow class
        Messenger.Register<bool>(GeneralToken.ClientDisconnected, DisconnectFromServer);
    }

    protected abstract void DisconnectFromServer(bool isDisconnected);
    protected abstract void RegisterTokens();
    protected abstract void UnRegisterTokens();

    ....
    ....
    ....

}
```

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: `Values types and types without a default constructor can be used as items within ResourceDictionary.` - Is that really *"cannot"*?

Comment: Is the solution as simple as adding a default (empty) constructor to your `BaseWindow` class?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Actually there is no 'not' in the message, if other cases citing the error are anything to go by...

Comment: @H.B. I suspect it's a typo, as I would expect to see the word "only" in the original wording.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, an 'only' would help...

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It has a default constructor

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your base window apparently, as the error states, needs a public default contructor (one without arguments), it also may not be abstract because an instance of it needs to be created.

Comment: There is something else, my BaseWindow is a abstract class with protected constructor without any params.

Comment: @SaberAmani: That doesn't sound good, most things XAML require public members.

Comment: But It's inheritance and I don't think it causes problem, Right ?

Comment: @SaberAmani: It does cause problems as you try to create an instance in XAML, this only works with a public constructor, also it cannot be abstract either, i just tested this.