# Parent and Child UserControl Error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have created two `Usercontrols` in my `WPF Application`! I want to access function of one Usercontrol via other. I just made one `usercontrol` parent of other and tried to access function of other but it generated Error that :

`Error 2   The type 'EditStory' cannot have a Name attribute. Value types and types without a default constructor can be used as items within a ResourceDictionary.`

My code is:

**AllStories -- Parent UserControl**

XAML-File

```
<dxdo:LayoutPanel Caption="Panel" Name="layoutPanel2">
                    <local:EditStory x:Name="editstorytab"/>
                </dxdo:LayoutPanel>
```

.CS File

```
public AllStories()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        editstorytab.MyParent = this;

    }
```

**EditStory -- Child UserControl**

.Cs File

```
 public AllStories MyParent { get; set; }
    public EditStory(AllStories parent)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
         MyParent = parent;
         EditDataRefresh();
    }
```

Can anyone Solve my problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11419707/84873) answer:

> Your base window apparently, as the error states, needs a public
>   default contructor (one without arguments), it also may not be
>   abstract because an instance of it needs to be created.

Comment: No other Alternative :(